# How can i set piechart data's values with arrays name jschart

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, pie-chart

I use piechart with javascript(jschart graphic library). When i set the piechart data's values with arrays name the piechart doesn't work. if i use the static variable the piechart works how can i solve that?

this is static variables

```
   function piechart()
    {
       var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie', 
            data: {
                labels: ["Galatasaray", "Fenerbahce", "Besiktas", "Diger"],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [12,4,19,3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
            ]
        }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                            beginAtZero: true                       

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

this is arrays name

```
 function piechart()
{
  int dizim=[5,9,8,7];
   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie', 
        data: {
            labels: ["Galatasaray", "Fenerbahce", "Besiktas", "Diger"],
            datasets: [{
                data: dizim,
                backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
        ]
    }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                        beginAtZero: true                       

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is int dizim a typo? Should it not be a var?

Comment: there is no `int` keyword in JS; plus even if did, it would possibly define integer not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please visit this site.. 
same question already answered
[draw pie chart from arrays in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411167/draw-pie-chart-from-arrays-in-highcharts)

hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by changing `int dizim=[5,9,8,7];` by `var dizim=[5,9,8,7];`